# Find the first occurence of a sets a combination of keys in a table by sql

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table in the following format

```
Name    ID  payment_date
A       1   31-Jan
C       3   31-Jan
B       2   31-Jan
C       3   28-Jan
D       4   29-Jan
B       2   30-Jan
A       1   25-Jan
C       3   26-Jan
D       4   2-Feb
B       2   3-Feb
A       1   4-Feb
B       3   5-Feb
```

I want to query the first occurrence of every combination of Name and ID. Please help me to write the query in sql.

Desired output

```
Name    ID  payment_date
A       1   25-Jan
B       2   30-Jan
B       3   5-Feb
C       3   26-Jan
D       4   29-Jan
```

Comment: did you try anything at all?

Comment: What database product are you using?

Comment: I am using vertica

Comment: Why is B3 not in your results?

Comment: Sorry, added it

Comment: Did you receive the proper answer? If not, why? If yes, a "thanks" and an accept answer is missing...

Answer (score 3):

You want the minimum date per `name` and `id`:

```
select name, id, min(payment_date)
from mytable
group by name, id
order by name, id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    NAME, ID, MIN(PAYMENT_DATE)
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY
    NAME, ID
ORDER BY
    NAME, ID;
```